# Deployment of custom app using package.xml

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, lightning-apps, package.xml, lightning-app-builder

I work at project that consists of Lightning App including two Lightning Component Tab. I needed to deploy it to another org and continue working. I retrieved all necessary components using package.xml and deployed it to target org. Deployment went without errors.

When I open my app, I see empty space and "No items" tab. I entered Lightning App Builder -> App settings -> User profiles and added System administrator. Nothing changed.

What else should I do to have it working?

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>54.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: You should add the Admin profile to make sure you retrieve all necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, that's the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the listed objects have Profile Permissions. As such, you should include the Admin profile to the package. This will make sure that the appropriate permissions are also retrieved for deployment to another organization.